# Correctly updating Jlist by calling firedatachanged

Tags: java, jlist

So i need to update the jList dynamically. I read that i have to use a fireData.... or something similar depending on the api.

I'm using AbstractListModel for the jList in the following code.

```
 /*private javax.swing.JList<String> anycast_users;*/

void set_user_model(){

       anycast_users.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>() {

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
            return anycast_users_num;
        }

        @Override
        public String getElementAt(int i) {
            return anycast_users_list[i];
        }
    });
    /*listeners and other init..*/
```

The AbstractListNodel has this function

```
protected void fireContentsChanged(Object source,
                   int index0,
                   int index1)
```

So, to update the list i initially tried

```
anycast_users.getModel().  //in a different function (updateList())
```

But as fireContentsChanged is protected i can't call it from here.
So, how to call the function correctly, and what additional changes is required?

Comment: Don't trigger events outside of the of model, only do so from the model itself

Comment: While [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835552/editing-item-in-jcombobox-dynamically/24836071#24836071) is based on `ComboBoxModel`, it's conceptually the same idea

Comment: @MadProgrammer the list(String array) is updated in a different function, so i need to refresh the jlist whenever the  'list' is updated. Hence i'm calling it from there. If this is wrong, or bad practice, then what should i do?

Comment: @MadProgrammer link is not there

Comment: So? It's still no one else's responsibility to trigger a model event other then the model.  Instead you need to pass the new list to the `ListModel` and allow it to deal with how it want's to update - PS fixed link

Comment: By passing it to the model it should in theory update the list automatically if I remember it right.

Comment: @AlexanderHeim You have two choices, you can either create a new `ListModel` based on the updated values and apply that to the `JList`, just beware that this will affect the selection and will cause the `JList` to scroll back to the first item OR you could create a diff, which would allow you to apply the changes made to the model and trigger incremental updates, which would be less of a visual change to the user

Comment: @AlexanderHeim Also, a `DefaultListModel` will provide mutable functionality (add and remove) for you

Comment: Wasn´t asking the question but thanks anyway. Though i still think that the way SWING let´s us handle list, tables and so on is just horribly inconvenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going with a solution suggested by MadProgrammer.

```
class anycastModel extends javax.swing.AbstractListModel<String>{


    @Override
    public int getSize() {
        return anycast_users_num;
    }

    @Override
    public String getElementAt(int i) {
       return anycast_users_list[i];
    }

    public void updateList(){

        fireContentsChanged(this, 0, anycast_users_num);
    }
}
void set_usermodel(){
    anycast_model=new anycastModel();
    anycast_users.setModel(anycast_model);
}
```

For updating

```
anycast_model.updateList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method in that class where you have access to the model and make something like this:

```
public ListModel<String> getAnycastUsersModel() {
  return this.anycast_users.getModel();
}
```

This way you can access it from wherever you want to.
And I would suggest you using DefaultListModel if you're able to :)

Comment: Since `ListModel` to does not have any mutable capabilities, not does it expose the any ability to trigger update events, I can't see how this would help